# Python imports are very slow - Anaconda python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, python-import

My python import statements have become extremely slow. I'm running python 2.7 locally using the Anaconda package. After importing modules, the code I wrote runs very quickly, it just seems to be the imports that take forever.

As an example, I ran a "tester.py" file with the follow code:

```
import timeit

x = timeit.timeit('import numpy as np')
print 'imported numpy in %s seconds'%x

x = timeit.timeit('import pandas as pd')
print 'imported pandas in %s seconds'%x

x = timeit.timeit('from Tkinter import Frame,Tk, Label, Checkbutton')
print 'imported Tkinter in %s seconds'%x

x = timeit.timeit('from tkFileDialog import askopenfilenames, asksaveasfilename')
print 'imported tkFileDialog in %s seconds'%x

x = timeit.timeit('import tkMessageBox')
print 'imported tkMessageBox in %s seconds'%x

x = timeit.timeit('import os')
print 'imported os in %s seconds'%x
```

Output from the command line is:

```
C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda>C:\Users\***\Desktop\tester.py
imported numpy in 5.22607264113 seconds
imported pandas in 13.7990192174 seconds
imported Tkinter in 3.95690550577 seconds
imported tkFileDialog in 3.62803133249 seconds
imported tkMessageBox in 1.50766849631 seconds
imported os in 1.87009742139 seconds
```

How can I diagnose what is happening and/or speed up the imports? I'm not really sure where to start.... Maybe re-installing Anaconda? Any insights or ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem does not come from python, but your pc instead ?
Have a look at processes and ram to see if nothing is eating all your resources.

Comment: Thanks for your response. On checking via Resource Monitor, about 30% ram (2.5gb/ 8gb) is being used... Would that be enough to cause such delays?

Comment: What do you have in `sys.path`? I guess having a slow network path (or several of them) there could cause imports to slow down a bit.

Comment: I have the defaults for the Anaconda package plus a few more:
C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests_kerberos-0.7.0-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\python27.zip
C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\DLLs

C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib
C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\plat-win
C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\lib-tk

C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda
C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages

(continued to next comment)

Comment: C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL
C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Sphinx-1.2.3-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\cryptography-0.8-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.8.1-py2.7.egg

Comment: Is the above sys.path list length likely to be the source of the long run time? I really appreciate the assistance and advice.

Comment: I am having same issue, and couldn't find a solution yet. With regular python (not Anaconda), those imports happen in second.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of timeit is not correct, you should pass number = 1 so that import statement is executed just once. By default timeit passes "number" as 1000000. No wonder it takes few seconds to import a module million times.

Having said that, python imports are in general slow and you will find some good advice on how to speed up imports (lazy imports, pre-compiled modules etc) on stackoverflow and other online sources.

Comment: ...but not on *this* page of stackoverflow, it seems.  Agree `number=1` should be used but in fact after the initial `import` the subsequent 999999 iterations will just be lightning-fast lookups into `sys.modules`.